# htaccess not properly rewriting urls

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, regex

This is a bit of a weird one. I'm doing some work on a server, and I need rewrite rules for directories that *actually exist* (in some cases, they are more than one level deep)

At the moment my .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^simfiles/([-\ a-zA-Z0-9:/]+)$ http://mydomain.com/?portal=simfiles&folder=$1 [L]
```

And this is working OK, for example, a url like:

```
mydomain.com/sifmiles/my-files
```

Will get redirected to

```
mydomain.com/?portal=simfiles&folder=my-files
```

Or in the case of a directory structure that is deeper than one level:

```
mydomain.com/sifmiles/my-files/more-of-my-files
```

Will get redirected to

```
mydomain.com/?portal=simfiles&folder=my-files/more-of-my-files
```

I wrote the regex so that it won't match things with a . in the path, because there are css and js files which reside in simfiles/somedirectory, and if I redirect everything then these cannot be loaded.

I tried a configuration like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^simfiles/([-\ a-zA-Z0-9:/\.]+)$ http://mydomain.com/?portal=simfiles&folder=$1 [L]
```

But that doesn't work, things still don't load properly.

So my first question is, how can I achieve this "properly"? I don't like my solution because it means redirects won't occur if the folder has a . in its name.

My second problem, is that while the redirection is happening properly, the url becomes:

```
http://mydomain.com/?portal=simfiles&folder=my-files
```

I want the URL to remain clean, like:

```
http://mydomain.com/sifmiles/my-files
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overthinking your regex. Since you're already checking whether the underlying file exists before the rewrite rule, you should be able to just match anything.

```
RewriteRule ^simfiles/(.+) /?portal=simfiles&folder=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This rule seems to do what I want. Except the issue with the 'nice url' not persisting remains. Using RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f and your rule, mydomain.com/simfiles/mydir1/mydir2 becomes: mydomain.com/simfiles/mydir1/mydir2/?portal=simfiles&folder=mydir1/mydir2

I would like the URL to remain as mydomain.com/simfiles/mydir1/mydir2

Comment: Turns out that the issue with urls not being rewritten lies elsewhere. This answer solved my other problem though.